# Compare one column from one dataframe to another with different sizes pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, lambda

So based on these two pandas data-frames:

1. I need to populate each row from the column df1.empId doing a
   conditional from df1.ElementPage if equal or less than the value of
   df2.ElementPage, if condition is met, fill with the value from
   df2.empId in df1.empId

df1:

```
|contact      |phone       |ElementPage|empId|
|-------------|------------|-----------|-----|
|Silvia Smith |513-123-4567|2          |     |
|Barbara Smith|513-123-4567|4          |     |
|Leimomi Yang |513-123-4567|6          |     |
|SaraSmith    |513-123-4567|8          |     |
|Naomi Thomas |513-123-4567|10         |     |
|Margot Thomas|513-123-4567|10         |     |
|Bill Anderson|513-123-4567|16         |     |
```

df2:

```
|empId  |ElementPage|
|-------|-----------|
|7      |1          |
|81     |3          |
|52     |5          |
|94     |7          |
|85     |9          |
|143    |11         |
|102    |13         |
|3      |15         |
|112    |17         |
|9      |19         |
```

how to suppose to be the output:

```
|contact      |phone       |ElementPage|empId|
|-------      |-----       |-----------|-----|
|Silvia Smith |513-123-4567|2          |7    |
|Barbara Smith|513-123-4567|4          |81   |
|Leimomi Yang |513-123-4567|6          |52   |
|SaraSmith    |513-123-4567|8          |94   |
|Naomi Thomas |513-123-4567|10         |85   |
|Margot Thomas|513-123-4567|10         |85   |
|Bill Anderson|513-123-4567|16         |3    |
```

I tried something like:

```
df1['empId'] = df1['empId'].apply(lambda x: x[df2['ElementText']] if x['ElementPage'] >= x[df2['ElementPage']] else 'No empId')
```

but is showing me this error:

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

To consider: df's aren't the same size and indexes on both starts on "0"

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want to merge on the closest higher or equal value of 'ElementPage' in df2. For this you can use [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
pd.merge_asof(df1.drop('empId', axis=1), df2, on='ElementPage')
```

output:

```
         contact         phone  ElementPage  empId
0   Silvia Smith  513-123-4567            2      7
1  Barbara Smith  513-123-4567            4     81
2   Leimomi Yang  513-123-4567            6     52
3      SaraSmith  513-123-4567            8     94
4   Naomi Thomas  513-123-4567           10     85
5  Margot Thomas  513-123-4567           10     85
6  Bill Anderson  513-123-4567           16      3
```

Comment: I'm not sure why my answer didn't go through on this, I was checking my post and I double-check, and OH! I just wanna say thanks because your answer works like a charm. Thank again.

Comment: @lug0lug0 do you mean you hadn't seen that someone had answered? If this solution worked for you, you can consider accepting the answer ;)